# Getting "repeat values" individually to calculate them separately

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I'm working on smart form of maintenance activities by XLSForm and trying to calculate the weightage of each question to evaluate the priorities of taking action based on the final score of the survey ether it is High or Low.

The engineer want to have weightages in each inspected assets like Transformers, RMU etc.

I designed the questions of these assets to be in the "repeat".

It might be two or more transformers inside the substations so the repeat will increase.

How can I get repeat values individually to calculate them separately?

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MMY1.png)

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaX9X.png)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  Are you saying that your `cal_total_xxx_leaking` field calculation is not working as expected?  If so, in what way?  If not, what do you actually mean by "get repeat values individually to calculate them separately"?